# jQuery addClass if div height changes

Tags: jquery

I have a div that has an expandable list in it. The div has a max-height of 450px on it so that the list doesn't expand beyond that. I have a set of arrows on the div that scroll the div up and down on click, but I need to add up/down arrows to the div only if it's height reaches 450px. Here is what I have so far...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#sidebar-container").addEventListener("overflow", function(){
if($("#sidebar-container").height() == 450) {
    $('.sidebar-arrow-up').addClass('arrow-show');
    $('.sidebar-arrow-down').addClass('arrow-show');
}
else{
    $('.sidebar-arrow-up').removeClass('arrow-show');
    $('.sidebar-arrow-down').removeClass('arrow-show');
}
},false);
</script>
```

I have tried on click event, but need this to check the height of the div without a user driven event.

link: http://shamounwp.theinfiniteclients.com/procedures/breast/types-of-procedures/choiceswhich-one-is-right-for-me/

Comment: A jQuery object has no `addEventListener` method, and there is no `overflow` event ?

Comment: I know this code isn't right, I've tried about 15 different things. Just showing what I have currently and seeing if anyone has a real answer.

Comment: look at window onload event or maybe document ready is enough

Comment: tried both of those, the problem is I need it to run multiple times, not just on page load. for example, if the div is only 400px when the page is loaded, then a user expands one of the parent list items, the script will not know to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from looking at the site, it looks like the div will only ever change size when you click on a list element. I think your best option would be to create a function like this

```
function checkSize(){
  if($("#sidebar-container").height() == 450) {
    $('.sidebar-arrow-up').addClass('arrow-show');
    $('.sidebar-arrow-down').addClass('arrow-show');
  }
  else{
    $('.sidebar-arrow-up').removeClass('arrow-show');
    $('.sidebar-arrow-down').removeClass('arrow-show');
  }
}
```

and then add a class to each list element such as .list-element and then have something like this in your window.load() or document.ready():

```
$('.list-element').click(function (){
  checkSize();
});
```

You can also call this function once at start of the page load so that it checks the initial size as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  checkSize();

  //additional page code
});
```

this will call the function once at the beginning to add the arrows initially (if needed) and then every time an item with the 'list-element' class is clicked, which will be your list elements, the things that cause your div to change heights

Comment: Thanks! added that and it seems to be working, only issue is that the click event checks the size of the div before the resize. is there a way to add a delay to the function to all the list to expand out?

Comment: hmm you could use something like `setTimeout(checkSize(), 1000);` to delay the function call by 1 second, but that seems like more of a roundabout solution. Are you using a plugin for the expanding list? that might make things harder, but most jquery functions can take a function handle as an argument and will call that function when they are complete, an example would be something like `.fadeout('slow', myFunc());` which would call myFunc upon completion of the fade. If you're doing the resizing yourself the best solution would be to add in the checkSize() function to be called on completion

Comment: sure thing! Like I said that's kind of a "dirty" solution, you might want to look for the function that does the resizing and see if you can have that call checkSize() on completion, that would be the cleanest and most dynamic solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `overflow: auto`.  That will only put a scrollbar on the div when the height of the content within the element exceeds the max-height of the element.

So in your css:

```
#sidebar-container {
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have that, but I'm wanting to use up/down arrows on the top/bottom of the div instead of the scrollbar.

Comment: ok, so when a user expands the list, check the height at that time.  If the height is greater then 450px, add the arrows.

Comment: the div is a sidebar list that has parent and child elements, so the div may start at 400px, but when a parent is clicked that list item appears making the height of the div greater.